# Getting Ambiguous match found exception while calling DeleteAsync

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I have a table which has code as primary key instead of Id, When I call `DeleteAsync` method I get the exception `Ambiguous match found`.

```
[Table("Test")]

public class Test: FullAuditedEntity<int>

{

[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
new public int Id { get; set; }
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public virtual int Code { get; set; }

_testRepository.DeleteAsync(code);
```

StackTrace:

```
   at System.RuntimeType.GetPropertyImpl(String name, BindingFlags 
bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type returnType, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
   at System.Type.GetProperty(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
   at System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.GetProperty(Type type, String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression expression, String propertyOrFieldName)
   at Abp.Domain.Repositories.AbpRepositoryBase`2.CreateEqualityExpressionForId(TPrimaryKey id) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Domain\Repositories\AbpRepositoryBase.cs:line 310
   at Abp.Domain.Repositories.AbpRepositoryBase`2.FirstOrDefault(TPrimaryKey id) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Domain\Repositories\AbpRepositoryBase.cs:line 108
   at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.Delete(TPrimaryKey id) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Repositories\EfCoreRepositoryBaseOfTEntityAndTPrimaryKey.cs:line 216
   at Abp.Domain.Repositories.AbpRepositoryBase`2.DeleteAsync(TPrimaryKey id) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Domain\Repositories\AbpRepositoryBase.cs:line 206
   at Castle.Proxies.Invocations.IRepository`2_DeleteAsync_58.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.PerformAsyncUow(IInvocation invocation, UnitOfWorkOptions options) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Domain\Uow\UnitOfWorkInterceptor.cs:line 83
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.IRepository`2Proxy_16.DeleteAsync(Int32 id)
   at Nec.Stanchion.Business.Services.Suppliers.SupplierAppService.<DeleteSupplier>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Users\viveknuna\source\repos\Stanchion\aspnet-core\src\Nec.Stanchion.Business.Services\Suppliers\SupplierAppService.cs:line 53
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ambiguous match found` is likely caused by property hiding of `Id` in Entity Framework. `FullAuditedEntity<int>` already defined `Id` identically to what you do, so you can remove that.

On another note, `_testRepository.DeleteAsync(code)` deletes by comparing the `Id`. To delete by `code`, do `_testRepository.DeleteAsync(test => test.Code == code);`