# Possible problem with aspnetzero & power tools

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

i created an entity, and when i add a row, all works OK, when i do a view (sometimes), update or delete, i get an 'internal error'. i have no idea what is the problem.

its a simple entity:[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccZ5t.png)[image: pic2]

i have downloaded the code from -1 month agoand happens on all entities i add with the power tools. any assistance is greatly appreciated.

> INFO  2019-02-18 22:03:44,609 [64   ] ore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker - Executed action OrthoResInfo.Web.Areas.App.Controllers.TblTable1sController.CreateOrEditModal (OrthoResInfo.Web.Mvc) in 624.4343ms
>   INFO  2019-02-18 22:03:44,609 [64   ] ft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware - Executed endpoint 'OrthoResInfo.Web.Areas.App.Controllers.TblTable1sController.CreateOrEditModal (OrthoResInfo.Web.Mvc)'
>   ERROR 2019-02-18 22:03:44,610 [64   ] nostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware - An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>   System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found.
>      at System.RuntimeType.GetPropertyImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type returnType, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
>      at System.Type.GetProperty(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression expression, String propertyOrFieldName)
>      at Abp.Domain.Repositories.AbpRepositoryBase`2.CreateEqualityExpressionForId(TPrimaryKey id) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Domain\Repositories\AbpRepositoryBase.cs:line 266
>      at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.FirstOrDefaultAsync(TPrimaryKey id) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Repositories\EfCoreRepositoryBaseOfTEntityAndTPrimaryKey.cs:line 118
>      at Abp.Threading.InternalAsyncHelper.AwaitTaskWithPostActionAndFinallyAndGetResult[T](Task`1 actualReturnValue, Func`1 postAction, Action`1 finalAction)
>      at OrthoResInfo.Nstable1.TblTable1sAppService.GetTblTable1ForEdit(EntityDto`1 input) in D:\ASPNetZero\Github\OrthoResInfo\src\OrthoResInfo.Application\Nstable1\TblTable1sAppService.cs:line 74
>      at Abp.Threading.InternalAsyncHelper.AwaitTaskWithPostActionAndFinallyAndGetResult[T](Task`1 actualReturnValue, Func`1 postAction, Action`1 finalAction)
>      at Abp.Threading.InternalAsyncHelper.AwaitTaskWithFinallyAndGetResult[T](Task`1 actualReturnValue, Action`1 finalAction)
>      at OrthoResInfo.Web.Areas.App.Controllers.TblTable1sController.CreateOrEditModal(Nullable`1 id) in D:\ASPNetZero\Github\OrthoResInfo\src\OrthoResInfo.Web.Mvc\Areas\App\Controllers\TblTable1sController.cs:line 42
>      at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ExceptionContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events) in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\Hosting\IdentityServerMiddleware.cs:line 72
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context)
>      at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\Hosting\BaseUrlMiddleware.cs:line 36

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Ambiguous match found exception while calling DeleteAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155968/getting-ambiguous-match-found-exception-while-calling-deleteasync)

Answer (score 0):

well, after alot of time, i found this post:  [Getting Ambiguous match found exception while calling DeleteAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155968/getting-ambiguous-match-found-exception-while-calling-deleteasync)

i had added IsDeleted and Id to my entities; hence the code when generated was bad.