# How to make composite unique key in ASP.NET Boilerplate?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I have a table which has the Id as primary key, I want to have a composite unique key on `Code` and `Value` column. I'm trying in this way.

```
[Table("Test")]

public class Test: FullAuditedEntity

{


[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public virtual int Code { get; set; }

[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public virtual int Value { get; set; }
```

But it's making the composite primary key not unique key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding solution for others.

Don't modify anything just add the below line

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Test>(b =>
        {
            b.HasIndex(e => new { e.Code, e.Value}).IsUnique();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class SomeClass : Entity<int>
{
    [Column("Code")]
    public override int Id {get; set;}

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }    
}
```

`[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` will make the Database to NOT create the Code column. What you need in reality is to override the Id and rename it to Code.

And to have a composite key, simply add

```
[Key]
public virtual int Value { get; set; }
```

field.