# Versionable Entities

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I´m working on a project using ASPNET Boilerplate where some entities must be versioned, so they have an Id and a versionNumber, where the same entity can have several versions like:

```
Documents:[
{Document:{id:1, version:1}}, 
{Docuemnt:{id:1, version:2}}]
```

So my question is if there is an easy way of doing this, like the implementation of Soft Delete, where I can intercept the update method so it creates a new version.

Comment: So you want to create a table with id and version as composite Pk or unique? Could you please explain your question a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override [`ApplyAbpConcepts`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/AbpDbContext.cs#L238) in your `DbContext` to create a new entity when your `Document` entity is modified, then reload the original entity so that its changes are not saved.
[`CancelDeletionForSoftDelete`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/6eccadb5d454f8f3d26bbd330f0d1ffd0455cbd6/src/Abp.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/AbpDbContext.cs#L394-L401) does something similar.

But just doing this won't work because primary key is unique. You can [create a composite key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192731/how-to-make-composite-unique-key-in-asp-net-boilerplate).

You will also have to handle relationships (i.e. foreign keys) to avoid linking to multiple versions.

Comment: Could you please explain "when your Document entity is modified, then reload the original entity so that its changes are not saved" .

Comment: [`CancelDeletionForSoftDelete`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/6eccadb5d454f8f3d26bbd330f0d1ffd0455cbd6/src/Abp.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/AbpDbContext.cs#L394-L401) does something similar.