# Disable SoftDelete for AbpUserRole

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate, soft-delete

By default, the `AbpUserRole` and `AbpRole` implement `ISoftDelete`. Is it possible to disable it?

I tried to do this:

```
[AbpAuthorize(AppPermissions.Pages_Administration_Roles_Delete)]
public async Task DeleteRole(EntityDto input)
{
    using (CurrentUnitOfWork.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.SoftDelete))
    {
        var role = await _roleManager.GetRoleByIdAsync(input.Id);
        var users = await UserManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(role.Name);

        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            CheckErrors(await UserManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, role.Name));
        }

        CheckErrors(await _roleManager.DeleteAsync(role));
    }
}
```

Although the filter is disabled in the current unit of work, it doesn't work. The entity is marked as deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answered in this topic: https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?p=6180#p6193

> Data filters work on selecting data. If your entity is SoftDelete, ABP always soft-deletes it and prevents actually deleting.
>
> You can override CancelDeletionForSoftDelete method in your DbContext and prevent cancellation conditionally.

So, like this:

```cs
protected override void CancelDeletionForSoftDelete(EntityEntry entry)
{
    if (IsSoftDeleteFilterEnabled)
    {
        base.CancelDeletionForSoftDelete(entry);
    }
}
```