# Implementation of Hard Delete for Entity which is being referred in other entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate, ef-core-2.0

I'm trying to implement hard delete for `FullyAuditedEntity` Entity `Test`. The primary key of `Test` is `Id`, which is being referred to a `TestTest2` entity as a foreign key. When I'm trying to delete a record from `Test` entity, it gives the below error.

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48624498/disable-softdelete-for-abpuserrole/48625417#48625417) question for implementation.

**TestAppService**

```
public async Task DeleteTest(EntityDto<string> input)
{
    using (CurrentUnitOfWork.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.SoftDelete))
    {
        await _TestRepository.DeleteTest(input);
        CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**TestRepository**

```
public async Task DeleteArticle(EntityDto input)
{
    await DeleteAsync(x => x.Id == input.Id);
}
```

**TestTest2**

```
[Table("TestTest2")]
public class TestTest2 : FullAuditedEntity
{
    [ForeignKey("TestId")]
    public virtual Test Test { get; set; }
    public virtual string TestId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Test2Id")]
    public virtual Test2Details Test2s { get; set; }
    public virtual int Test2Id { get; set; }
}
```

**MyProjectDbContextModelSnapshot**

```
modelBuilder.Entity("MyCompany.MyProject.Business.Model.Tests.TestTest2Association", b =>
{
    b.HasOne("MyCompany.MyProject.Business.Model.Tests.Test", "Test")
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey("TestId");

    b.HasOne("MyCompany.MyProject.Business.Model.Test2s.Test2Details", "Test2s")
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey("Test2Id")
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
});
```

> ERROR 2018-02-28 18:10:09,840 [26   ]
>   Mvc.ExceptionHandling.AbpExceptionFilter - An error occurred while
>   updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted
>   with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_TestTest2_Test_TestId". The conflict
>   occurred in database "MyProjectDb", table "dbo.TestTest2", column
>   'TestId'. The statement has been terminated.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConMyCompanytion.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConMyCompanytion, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) 
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConMyCompanytion.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConMyCompanytion, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) 
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConMyCompanytionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean
>   asyncWrite, String method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConMyCompanytion
>   conMyCompanytion, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2
>   parameterValues)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConMyCompanytion
>   conMyCompanytion, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConMyCompanytion
>   conMyCompanytion)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConMyCompanytion
>   conMyCompanytion)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(Tuple`2
>   parameters)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState
>   state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy
>   strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1
>   commandBatches, IRelationalConMyCompanytion conMyCompanytion)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1
>   entries)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1
>   entriesToSave)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean
>   acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean
>   acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)    at
>   Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpDbContext.SaveChanges() in
>   D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\AbpDbContext.cs:line
>   198    at
>   Abp.Zero.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpZeroCommonDbContext`3.SaveChanges() in
>   D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore\Zero\EntityFrameworkCore\AbpZeroCommonDbContext.cs:line
>   154    at
>   Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.EfCoreUnitOfWork.SaveChangesInDbContext(DbContext
>   dbContext) in
>   D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Uow\EfCoreUnitOfWork.cs:line
>   159    at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.EfCoreUnitOfWork.SaveChanges()
>   in
>   D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Uow\EfCoreUnitOfWork.cs:line
>   60    at
>   MyCompany.MyProject.Business.Services.Tests.TestAppService.d__12.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__12.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__10.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__14.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__23.MoveNext()
>   INFO  2018-02-28 18:10:09,873 [26   ]
>   etCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor - Executing ObjectResult,
>   writing value Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext. INFO 
>   2018-02-28 18:10:09,922 [26   ]
>   ore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker - Executed action
>   MyCompany.MyProject.Business.Services.Tests.TestAppService.DeleteTest
>   (MyCompany.MyProject.Business.Services) in 3940.4091ms INFO 
>   2018-02-28 18:10:10,158 [26   ]
>   soft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost - Request finished in
>   4037.4507ms 500 application/json; charset=utf-8

**Note:** It should delete the entry from `Test` and `Test2` tables.

**Update**

The below anwer works pretty well but I have some specific requirement. `Test` Entity `Id` is being referred in other tables like `TestTest2`, `TestTest3`, `TestTest4`, `TestTest5`. When I delete a record from `Test` table, it should delete from all tables. **But I also need to call the other dependent tables ( for example `TestTest2`, `TestTest3`, `TestTest4`, `TestTest5`) Delete method to do some extra cleanup specific to that entity (for example `TestTest2`, `TestTest3`, `TestTest4`, `TestTest5`).**

**TestRepository**

```
public async Task DeleteTest(EntityDto input)
{
    await DeleteAsync(input.Id);

    _TestTest2Repository.Delete(x => x.TestId == input.Id);
    _TestTest3Repository.Delete(x => x.TestId == input.Id);
    _TestTest4Repository.Delete(x => x.TestId == input.Id);
    _TestTest5Repository.Delete(x => x.TestId == input.Id);
}
```

Comment: It's hard to follow your string based configuration, but looks like you forgot to mark `TestTest2.TestId` property as required, thus by convention EFC does not set cascade delete on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on [Cascade Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete):

> For optional relationships: **ClientSetNull** (default)
>   - Effect on dependent/child in database: None

You have to configure the delete behavior using Fluent API in your DbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TestTest2>()
            .HasOne(t => t.Test)
            .WithMany()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Comment: No need to add migration and run Update-Database after making this change?

Comment: You should do that.